# keyframes in css doesn't work properly using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I want to add an animation dynamically using `javascript` to play an animation after a user clicked on it. e.g imagine [connect 4 game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four), the purpose is to play animation from top of the board to where the bead should be placed. the problem is that the style successfully added to the document but it doesn't work properly!

Here is what I have implemented:

```
function changeColor(i, j){
    var div = document.querySelector(`.cell-${i}-${j}`);
    div.style.backgroundColor = currentTurn;

    var style = document.querySelector('style');
    var keyframe = `\
        @keyframes animation-${i}-${j} {\
            0% {\
                top: 0%;\
            }\
            100% {\
                top: 20%;\
            }\
        }\
    \
    `
    div.style.animationName = `animation-${i}-${j}`;
    div.style.animationDuration = '2s';
    style.innerHTML += keyframe;
}
```

> currentTurn has the value of "red" | "blue".

I don't know why the animation isn't played! the dom is like the following picture: 
[image]

Comment: You probably need to add keyframe to the style *before* starting the animation.

Comment: @Gerard would you please explain more explicitly?

Comment: **style.innerHTML += keyframe;** move that line up, so it is above **div.style.animationName =** and try again

Comment: @Gerard Unfortunately, It doesn't work properly

Comment: top with percentage value is relative to height of parent element, if there is no height it won't work + the element need to be positioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below.

```js
function changeColor(i, j) {
  var div = document.querySelector(`.cell-${i}-${j}`);
  div.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

  var style = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[2];
  var keyframe = `\
        @keyframes animation-${i}-${j} {\
            0% {\
                top: 0%;\
            }\
            100% {\
                top: 20%;\
            }\
        }\
    \
    `;
  style.innerHTML += keyframe;
  div.style.animationDuration = '2s';
  div.style.animationName = `animation-${i}-${j}`;
}
changeColor(1, 1);
```

```html
<style>
.cell-1-1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
<div class="cell-1-1"></div>
```

Comment: keeping `style.innerHTML += keyframe;` at the end will also work, try it

Comment: I have tried it in my own code and it works in static mode, but the problem is that it doesn't work dynamically!

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi see my comment in your question, the issue is not the animation, it's the top with percentage value